Finding the remainder when dividing by a polynomial
Consider the problem: Find the remainder when $x^8$ is divided by $x^3+1$.
One way to do this is to use $x^3=-1$ and repeatedly reduce $x^8$ until it is less than degree $3$, which is the final answer.
My question is: Does this strategy always work for all dividends and quotients? If not, what is a counterexample?
The standard technique is to write the division like this $$x^8=(x^3+1)q(x)+(ax^2+bx+c)$$ and plug in the 3 roots to get a system of equations.
My next question is: What if I want to divide by $x^3+x^2$? There are only 2 roots to plug into the equation. What is the standard technique? Take derivative and plug in the double root again?

I though the standard technique was long division, so $x^8 = (x^3+x^2)x^5 -x^7 $ $=(x^3+x^2)(x^5-x^4) +x^6 = \cdots $ $= (x^3+x^2)(x^5-x^4+x^3-x^2+x-1) +x^2$

You can write $x^{8}$ as $(x^{8}+x^{5})-x^{5}$. Division by $x^{3}+1$ yields $x^{5}$ for the first term. You can then apply the same method to the second term.

Change the dividend to $x^{1000}$, and your standard technique doesn't work.

The way I always learned it was long division. That is, as follows:
$x^3 + x^2$ goes $x^5$ times into $x^8$, with a remainder of $x^8 - x^5(x^3 + x^2) = -x^7$.
$x^3 + x^2$ goes $-x^4$ times into $-x^7$, with a remainder of $-x^7 - (-x^4)(x^3 + x^2) = x^6$.
$x^3 + x^2$ goes $x^3$ times into $x^6$, with a remainder of $x^6 - x^3(x^3 + x^2) = -x^5$.
$x^3 + x^2$ goes $-x^2$ times into $-x^5$, with a remainder of $-x^5 - (-x^2)(x^3 + x^2) = x^4$.
$x^3 + x^2$ goes $x$ times into $x^4$, with a remainder of $x^4 - x(x^3 + x^2) = -x^3$.
$x^3 + x^2$ goes $-1$ times into $-x^3$, with a remainder of $-x^3 - (-1)(x^3 + x^2) = x^2$.
$x^3 + x^2$ does not go into $x^2$ -- therefore, $x^2$ is the remainder.
Therefore, $x^8 = (x^3 + x^2)(x^5 - x^4 + x^3 - x^2 + x - 1) + x^2.$
This should be applicable to any two polynomials (where the degree of the dividend is higher than that of the divisor) and in addition is easy to do on paper (with the traditional long division notation).

This will be extremely tedious if the dividend is much messier and higher degree.

Yes, but many methods are extremely tedious with high degree polynomials. It's simple and efficient if you code it, and as I said the shorthand on paper is easy to use (just like arithmetic long division, but with coefficients instead of digits). The way I wrote is a bit of overkill, but you could easily write it in a few lines of LaTeX.

What I would call the "standard" method is polynomial long division, which does the job - as illustrated in the earlier post.  Yes, sometimes it takes time (especially if you're doing it with pen & paper), so knowing alternate ways could help in some cases.
For an alternate method, consider looking at everything $\pmod {x^3+x^2}$.  Then $x^3 \equiv -x^2 \implies x^4 \equiv -x^3\equiv x^2 \implies x^8 \equiv x^4 \equiv x^2 $ and you're done.
Essentially, this is the same alternate method you used in your division with $x^3+1$.
